# Kendo UI Angular 4 components override styles

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, styles

I have a requirement to change the font-size of the entire application when we click on an icon in the header. I am using all Kendo components.

I tried adding `styles.scss` from `@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";` with `.sample { font-size: 40px; }` and appending the `sample` class to the body element of the page:

```
<div [ngClass]="{sample: (boolVar == true)}">
```

I could see the style sample added to the root element when I inspect it but I do not see any font changes in Kendo UI components... Could someone shed some light on this?

Much appreciated for any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override the styles in the element you first need to add the `!important` flag to your styling.

Furthermore, for this styling to penetrate into the Angular components you need to use `/deep/`.

You also need to add the wildcard selector `*` to apply the style to all elements under `.sample`.

Try this:

```
/deep/ .sample * { font-size: 40px !important; }
```

**FYI:**

1. `/deep/` should be replaced sometime with a better solution. In the mean time this is the only available option.
2. If on some element there already is a `font-size` styling with the `!important` flag, your style will be overridden by it.

p.s. This setting will apply the same font-size to all elements, no matter where they are. I'm not sure it's what you really want in your application...

Comment: Note that /deep/ is deprecated and should be replaced with ::ng-deep

Comment: Yes, like I stated, `/deep/` should be replaced at some point. However, using `::ng-deep` isn't that much better since it is deprecated too and will be dropped alongside `/deep/`. The Angular team does recommend using `::ng-deep` for a "broader compatibility with the tools" but they will drop `/deep/` and both its aliases, `>>>` and `::ng-deep`, together at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on a theme level pretty easily! Kendo UI for Angular is set up to use Sass variables to customize various aspects of a theme, including a `$font-size` variable. Here's a list of all the available themes:

- [Default](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-default/customization/)
- [Bootstrap](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-bootstrap/customization/) (also inherits from Bootstrap v4 as a default)
- [Material](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-material/customization/)

As you can see from the links above, each of these themes has a `$font-size` variable that you can customize to fit your application needs.

Note: this kind of customization will have to generate the new CSS either through webpack or the build process of the theme itself [as mentioned here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#toc-customizing-themes).

If you want this to be updated dynamically and on-the-fly when a user selects a value from a drop down this can be a bit trickier. I'm not 100% aware fo the best approach, but the blanket `* { ... !important; }` probably will work (although I'm always cautious when I see this). Perhaps having multiple style sheets that you swap out depending on the font size could work? Another alternative would be to have a function that updates the CSS style of the elements on your page, including the Kendo UI components. At this point you would have to find out which CSS classes apply to the widgets on your page and tweak them accordingly.